# require("electron").app is undefined. I npm installed fresh modules. Unsure what to do

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

Yesterday, I was developing on Electron perfectly fine. Then I hop onto my computer to realize Electron isn't working at all now.

I removed `node_modules` and did a fresh `npm install`

package.json:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^1.4.7"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "electron-debug": "^1.1.0"
  }
...
```

This is the [error](https://ghostbin.com/paste/4co2k) I got.

I followed the suggestions used of previous issues of this problem. Nothing is resolving it.

Electron is not installed globally. Everything should be self contained in the directory.

[npm list](https://ghostbin.com/paste/5xxrr)

Most of this code was taken from [electron boilerplate](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-boilerplate)

Edit:

main process:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;

// adds debug features like hotkeys for triggering dev tools and reload
require('electron-debug')({
    showDevTools: true
});

// prevent window being garbage collected
let mainWindow;

function onClosed() {
    // dereference the window
    // for multiple windows store them in an array
    mainWindow = null;
}

function createMainWindow() {
    const display = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay();

    const win = new electron.BrowserWindow({
        width: display.workArea.width,
        height: display.workArea.height
    });

    const projectPath = path.dirname(path.dirname(__dirname));

    win.loadURL(`file://${projectPath}/static/index.html`);
    win.on('closed', onClosed);

    return win;
}

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (!mainWindow) {
        mainWindow = createMainWindow();
    }
});

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow();
});
```

Comment: Could you include the code that's causing the error? You might have just mistyped the import in some way.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I edited with main process code.

Comment: Try running `require.resolve('electron')` and logging the output in your main file to check that it's requiring the module you expect.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I did just that. output of each variable. `electron: /Users/user/Programming/electron-project/node_modules/electron/index.js` and `app: undefined`

Comment: Looks like that's fine - my suggestion would be to try removing `node_modules` and doing a fresh `npm install`. Your code itself doesn't seem to have any problems, especially if it's straight from the boilerplate.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I already did that. Multiple times. Installing electron in different ways and globally too.

Comment: To make matters even more odd. I use a simple boilerplate and it all works fine. I never touch or do anything with the main process of electron. I have only dealt with rendering html and js.

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you clone a boilerplate repo, install fresh dependencies and run? If so, it's probably something global interfering with Electron. Otherwise, I would be tempted just to use the working one, since I have no idea what's happened to your current module.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Ok, so lame. I cannot seem to reproduce my error on the boilerplate. Makes no sense. It was literally working yesterday and I changed nothing.

Comment: Is your issue pretty much solved then? Sorry it's not a more satisfying answer, though that's often the case with npm/Node issues.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Oh this is so weird. So, I think it must of been a Atom terminal plugin that broke everything somehow. I am taking the rendering process. Copying it into the boilerplate's rendering process file. When I run using the plugin terminal. it crashes, but when I run on my normal terminal it runs. Also, there are some bugs reports from the terminal. Thinking it may have screwed with npm somehow. OK it fixed.

Answer (score 16):

So, in my case. Issue was resolved by using my original terminal rather than a plugin terminal for Atom.

For anyone out there. Double check with your vanilla terminal or even editor to double check.

Comment: Did anyone ever spot the reason behind this?

Comment: I was having this problem while debugging an electron app using vs code. I have added a configuration file similar to [this](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process-vscode). Make sure to un-check 'All Exceptions' and 'Uncaught Exceptions' from the debugger window. It should debug smoothly.

Comment: Same thing happened to me until I exited **tmux** :(